# Root user can not login to vsphere client - but can login to ssh and web gui

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vsphere-client

I have VMware Vsphere appliance installed (5.1.0a)

I can access the web interface and login with root user and my password

[image]

but if I want to login with the vsphere client, I get wrong username and password error.

[image]

[image]

- I tried to change the password in the web gui to 1-8 - I still get the same error.

ideas?

Comment: Have you checked that Root has the correct roles?